# CPAN modules for computing integer hash keys based on short strings

Tags: function, hash, integer, cpan

I'm looking for a CPAN module that will take a short string:

```
my $hash_value = hash_this('short string not too long');
```

And hash it into an integer key:

```
say $hash_value;

12345671234    # an integer key
```

Answer (score 0):

Digest::MD5 should work:

http://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::MD5

With the binary, you should be able to convert it using it:

Math::BaseCnv

Comment: I'm currently using this but I would like the output in integer form: 2342345334

Comment: $md5->digest returns a binary then you just need to convert it to an int or is there a different problem?

Comment: What is "0b" in oct "0b$bin"?

Comment: If EXPR starts off with "0b", it is
               interpreted as a binary string

Comment: use 5.10.0;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5);

my $binary_key = md5("something");       

say oct("0b$binary_key");

# prints 0

Comment: I will try this out later tonight to confirm, but Math::BaseCnv should do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you need an hash that is only 32-bit or 64-bit long*, that is, if you need an hash of the type used in computer science terms such as "[hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)" and NOT an [hash in the cryptography meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) (which CAN'T be that short and strong at the same time) you can use CRC32 or one of its friends.

OTOH if you need a cryptographically strong hash function, I would [avoid MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Vulnerability) and use SHA-256 nowadays.

```
use String::CRC32;

$crc = crc32("some string");
```

*: I don't know how big is a perl integer value, so I might be wrong there

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [Algorithm::Nhash](http://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Nhash) to solve this exact problem. It generates a cheap hash from a string and optionally does modulo arithmetic to throw the strings into buckets.